# Using props.data with MDBNav, how to activate the active TAB or LINK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdbootstrap, mdbreact

With ReactJS i am using MDBNav from MDBreact.

[image]

This is the code od the container where is props.data defined:

```
import React from 'react'
import MiTabs from "../componentes/MiTabs";

class VpnList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    vpn: [
      {
        nombre: 'Test1',
        activo: true,
        enlace: '#!',
      },
      {
        nombre: 'Test2',
        activo: false,
        enlace: '#!',
      },
      {
        nombre: 'Test3',
        activo: false,
        enlace: '#!',
      },
      {
        nombre: 'Test4',
        activo: false,
        enlace: '#!',
      }
    ]
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/*
        <MiTabs data={this.state.vpn} /> <br />
        <h2> Create an article </h2>
        <CustomForm requestType="post" articleID={null} btnText="Create" />
        */}
        <MiTabs  data={this.state.vpn}/>



      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default  VpnList;
```

This is the component code:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MDBNav, MDBNavItem, MDBNavLink } from "mdbreact";

const MiTabs = props => {

return (

  <BrowserRouter>
    <MDBNav className="nav-tabs mt-5">

    {props.data.map(a => (
      <MDBNavItem key={a.nombre}>  <MDBNavLink to={a.enlace}>{a.nombre} </MDBNavLink>  </MDBNavItem>
      ))}



      <MDBNavItem>
        <MDBNavLink  active to="#!">Active</MDBNavLink>
      </MDBNavItem>

      <MDBNavItem>
        <MDBNavLink to="#!">NO Active</MDBNavLink>
      </MDBNavItem>

    </MDBNav>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default  MiTabs;
```

Every thing is working but there is a problem with "active" is not showing up.

The problem is coming from here:

[image]

The CSS I am using is:

```
import 'mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css';
import './css/bootstrap.css';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
```

If i remve the active option from the code is always active all the tabs.
I shoutl be active on ly one when cliked, but now no one is active.

From somehere i receiveig this "active" class.
I din´t find from where. How to debug this problem?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add prop `link` to `MDBNavLink`. MDBNavLink is a `NavLink` from `react-router-dom`, but in a component like tabs and pills you should use `Link` from `react-router-dom`

Check this solution:

```
    import React from "react";
    import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { MDBNav, MDBNavItem, MDBNavLink } from "mdbreact";

    const MiTabs = props => {

    return (

      <BrowserRouter>
        <MDBNav className="nav-tabs mt-5">
        {props.data.map(a => (
          <MDBNavItem> 
   //Add a link prop to component below
             <MDBNavLink link active='true' to={a.enlace}>
                {a.nombre} 
             </MDBNavLink>  
          </MDBNavItem>
          ))}

          <MDBNavItem>
   //Add a link prop to component below
            <MDBNavLink link active to="#!">Active</MDBNavLink>
          </MDBNavItem>
          <MDBNavItem>

   //Add a link prop to component below
            <MDBNavLink link to="#!">NO Active</MDBNavLink>
          </MDBNavItem>

        </MDBNav>

      </BrowserRouter>

      );
    };

    export default  MiTabs;
```

This code should work properly now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `active` option, not `activo`:

```
<MDBNavItem key={a.nombre}><MDBNavLink active={a.activo} to={a.enlace}>{a.nombre} </MDBNavLink></MDBNavItem>
```

By doing {a.active} you just add `true` to MDBNavLink (which doesn't make sense), you need to add `active={true}` instead

Comment: I had tried it and it didn't work.Below I add one natively as MDBreact example but not workig. 
Now I see it's something else. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Kentron.dna what do you mean?

Comment: I have added it as you have suggested. Still not working. But I am also adding the native way: whithout using JS and also not working.

Comment: I just posted in a new post all the details.

Comment: You need to also add a key={a.nombre} to MDBNavItem

Comment: oh! sorry.  Key added, 
it seems that is not the problem. :-(

Comment: Please edit this question with your latest code and show the entire component. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210337/discussion-between-kentron-dna-and-tudor-gergely).